# Should we edit a question title that's too vague?

Tags: discussion, questions, editing

Sometimes the OP is trying to describe the problem with terms that can't be said usual, maybe because he's expert of another application or maybe he's not expert at all. The result is a maybe well written question, with picture showing the problem, but lacking of those keywords that are immediately capable of exposing the issue.

One of the latest example could be:

[I have a face that is causing me a lot of trouble and I do not know the technical term of this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86901/i-have-a-face-that-is-causing-my-a-lot-of-trouble-and-i-do-not-know-the-technica).

From now on I will refer to the title, but the same can be said for the content in the body of the post too.

The title doesn't give any help in describing the problem itself, it just mentions a face. It can be almost anything, and I may guess it will be shown in the seach page when someone will look for a solution to a problem related to faces, with all the other question with titles like that.

Should I edit it to better specify what the post is about? Or should I leave as the OP wrote it?

---

The [editing page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing) of the rules says to feel free to edit...

> ... any time you see a post that needs improvement ...

but I'm not sure that editing that way would be an improvement of the post in *global* terms.

I personally don't find titles like that useful, because they are not saying much about the issue. I'm not inclined to look into the question (but I was curious.. eheh), I would change them all believing that this would make it easier to anyone to choose where to spend our time in aswering or finding a solution to our problem.

But maybe for someone who don't even know those keywords, someone who shares the same level of knowledge of the OP about the topic, those are the **right** words, those are clearly describing the issue the way he would have done himself. Also, knowing what the problem exactly is about, is half, if not more, of the solution. Heavily editing the body in this sense would be basically answering the problem, but there's a dedicated space for that.

Here's some links I visited while trying to find an answer:

[How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

[Micro Editing, does everything need to be perfect?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/241/micro-editing-does-everything-need-to-be-perfect)

[Add content to make a post easier to find](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2347/add-content-to-make-a-post-easier-to-find)

Comment: Yes, of course you should edit the title. Put forth the improvement and see if others agree. There is no edict to the contrary. Edits can be rolled back. You can put the old title in the body. What is the worst that will happen to you if there is disagreement?

Comment: Do not sweat it. Improve and edit.

Comment: People who ask questions here are somewhat expected to have some previous tutorial knowledge of Blender. These tutorials can introduce them to Blender terminology, mistakes and triumphs. The OP may want to know such terms. You can place you edits at the top, and leave your older text nearer the bottom. Never touch the .... I am a newbie, I need it done today and I was just browsing the entire internet and saw this incredible mind boggling CG3D effect. This forum typically happens in the English Language so some people may (quietly) appreciate the assistance to their 2nd or 3rd Language.

Answer (score 4):

You are 100% right, edit away (but read this answer first).

I remember maybe a year and a half ago (or longer) having this same question. I came to the conclusion that there is no reason to not edit a post when a few things are true.

1. You understand the question enough to make it clearer.
2. There is something to fix.

About point one, if the question is so unclear that you have to guess what the OP wants just to make your edit, then you are most often better off simply casting a close vote as "unclear" then trying to edit it.
In your linked example, and many such examples where the OP has zero knowledge and does not even know how to describe the problem, yet it is easy to spot and correctly depict; then edit it - simple as that.
Be careful of two things though, one that you really do know what the issue is, and second that you do not so radically change the post that the original intent is lost.

Now about "radically changing the post" even to the extent that you kind of answered his question by your edit. Again tread lightly. There is a faint gray line between a good edit and going too far, one which you must use your own discretion when editing. For something to go from, my thoughts go like this: the more unclear the post, the more you can edit and take it away from the original. *But keep the original intent*, that is key.
I can remember some edit I made where the OP did not know what to call his problem, in my edit I basically answered his question in the alt text for one of his images (I now do not remember what the issue was). Is that odd? maybe. does it fit with SE's Q&A format? I think it still does. There is now a question that is a little bit clearer, and it has at least one answer. At the end of the day isn't that want really matters? Just clear questions and answers to help people.

In the [linked example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/86901/revisions), the question is clearly about the deformations from the sub surface modifier and the N-gon on the bottom. The OP does not know that, his only intent is getting his model to not look like that (even saying that he does not know the terms to use). So by you editing, adding in the proper terminology, changing the question to make it clearer, you are not only staying true to the OP's intent, but helping him in the process. (Good concise, clear questions get more attention and answers than ones which are unclear.)

About point two don't worry, for a post like this example there are most definitely things to make better. It is just a general "rule" of mine, if there is nothing (major) to edit then dont bother. A single misspeelled word, or a misplaced comma is not going to be the end of the world.

Comment: I agree with David. Anything that might make it easier for others to understand the question is helpful. Vague titles like "Problem with rendering", "How do I fix this?" or "Help, blender is broken!!!!" are not conducive to right answers. Clear and concise  titles,  questions and answers is what makes this site useful (in my opinion)